# "Unavailable: Socket closed" error when training on TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu

When training my transformer model on TPU I am getting the following error:

```
UnavailableError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unavailable: Socket closed
  (1) Invalid argument: Unable to find a context_id matching the specified one (13089686768223941123). Perhaps the worker was restarted, or the context was GC'd?
```

My data is divided to buckets depending on sequence length to get the best performance:

1. Length less or equal to 8
2. from 9 to 16
3. from 17 to 24

I am loading every batch from random bucket.

When I access every bucket first time - tensorflow kernel creates a new graph and retraces model.

The error happening on the third retracing. So I have no error if I train from any two buckets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand - it is a bug in tf 2.3.

I switched to 2.2.0 and the error disappeared.